# Water coming up from concrete in middle of basement

Tags: plumbing, basement, sump-pump, flooding

So after a major snow storm, about 10 inches, two 60 degree days of melting it, and then heavy rain all day the next day I go down to my basement where right in the middle was a giant pool of water above the concrete.

There is a sump pump in the basement but it’s completely dry as if it never saw any water ever.

Not sure what’s going on here and if any one can help with some advice please let me know.

I added a video showing where it is.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d3gB1W4zPnw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Do you also have a drain in the floor?  Are you in a built up area with storm/sewer drains?

Comment: Yes I am, there are multiple drains in the floor around the basement. We checked those and nothing seems backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Moisture is either coming up from below (a rising water table) or its coming from the surrounding ground water in the saturated soil, or both.

If it comes up from a rising water table, it will enter the living space from below through cracks in the slab (control joints in the slab and/ or around the perimeter where the slab meets the wall).

If it comes from the surrounding ground water, it COULD enter the living space through the wall, especially if the EXTERIOR side of the foundation wall is not sealed properly.

Either way the moisture enters the living space it will need to be collected and disposed. Water that comes from below can be collected by your sump pump. Often they are at the high point on the slab or undersized to keep up.

I think the best way to collect it is on the exterior side of the foundation wall is in drainrock and a perf pipe laid 6”-8” below the interior basement slab.

To keep the subsurface water from seeping through the wall, I recommend installing a moisture barrier on the exterior side of the foundation wall and install a 2” thick plastic mesh on the wall to allow water to flow down to the perf pipe. If dirt is allowed to be backfilled against the wall, the dirt could hold the moisture giving it a chance to seep through the wall.

Once collected it needs to be disposed by extending a solid pipe over an embankment or in a collection well and pumped away.

This may be the most expensive method of solving the problem, but it’s sure to work.

Comment: I do already have a sump pump down there and never see any water in it.

Comment: So it’s located at a high point in the slab?

Comment: Yes, we took a look and the sump pump is located at the high point of the slab. The area where the water came in is about 10-15ft from that sump pump.

Comment: You can either move the sump pump to the low point (where the water is coming in) or construct a trench that allows you to control where the water runs and extend it to the existing sump pump location. Both are messy and will take time and money. Depending on the quantity of water, you could just “broom” the water into the existing sump pump a few times a year.

Comment: I don’t know if this is a cause also but I had a furnace guy come by the day before this happened to do a routine check on my furnace. In the description of work he did he says, “blew the drains out” is it possible that caused something

Comment: I talked to the previous homeowners too who lived here for 10 years and they said this is something that never happened before.

Comment: Hmmm… of course they’re going to say that. If they admit it and didn’t disclose it, they’d be liable and would have to pay to fix it. 

Or blame it on climate change.

Comment: This is a tough one. I’m not entirely sure what has happened here nor what to do.

Comment: Best option I’m considering is to not put carpet back down in this area, decorate the concrete floor around here a little bit and wait for the spring to see what happens.

Comment: Just a update here, we ran a camera down the gutter downspouts and their clogged, pools of water sitting in them, the pipes are corroded and crushed does this sound like a possible root cause?